# Blazemeter (JMeter test) zip file upload fail

Tags: file-upload, jmeter, blazemeter

I get `Non HTTP response message: /home/jmeter/my_file-to-upload.zip (No such file or directory)` when uploading zip file in BlazeMeter.

But logs state that file is stored as expected `INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Stored: /home/jmeter/my_file-to-upload.zip`

I added test file along with jmx file when creating test as instructed [here](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420175-Uploading-Files-Shared-Folders). Also, have gone through BlazeMeter blogs and tutorials, nothing helped.

This test works perfectly fine executed locally or in Team Service, but I need it in BlazeMeter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blazemeter platform automatically extracts any zip file that is being uploaded, and thats the reason your test is unable to find the required file.

As a workaround, you can upload the file in a different format, and change the upload path to match the new file format.

For example: Change the zip format to gzip, and change the upload path in your script to be /home/jmeter/my_file-to-upload.gz instead of /home/jmeter/my_file-to-upload.zip.

If there are other questions we can help with, feel free to contact us at support@blazemeter.com

Blazemeter Support Team

Comment: Thanks. I already use a different format. The problem is I must test zip files being uploaded to my app as well.

Comment: Try archiving the ZIP in another ZIP. BM will probably extract the outer ZIP only, leaving you with the ZIP file you actually wish to upload in your scenario.